# What service can i use to send push notifications on IOS with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, parse-platform, push-notification

What service can i use to send push notifications to my ios app? I don't want to use parse because its in objective-c. Is there another push notification service that uses swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift to send push notifications via Parse.com.

Find out more in their documentation here:
https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/iOS

(NOTE: Press the 'Swift' button in the lower-right of the blue example box to see the example in Swift code.)